# Add a pop up wait message in form action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form action which generates the report. I want to add a message pop up like `Please wait the report is loading`

How can I do this in js.

```
 <form action="step50/generateReport" method="GET" id="form_generate">
      <input style="margin-top: 20px;" type="submit" id="btnGenerate"  value="Generate"/>      
</form>
```

I am trying this:

```
function popupProcessStatus(){                        
              $.fancybox({href:'#display_status_inline', closeBtn: true, helpers:{overlay: {closeClick:false}}});                            
        }

<div id="display_status_inline" style="display: none">     
            <br>
            <p>Please wait until the report is generated.</p>                                               
        </div>
```

But not sure where to call this function so as to display this when the btn is clicked and go off when the report is generated.

Answer (score 1):

just call the function on submit:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form_generate");
form.addEventListener("submit",popupProcessStatus,false);
```

Comment: Yes, but make sure your function is available there